# Issue with fullpage.js (section fp-section fp-is-overflow active fp-completely)

Tags: html, css, height, css-position, fullpage.js

I want to have my container in this section with height 100% insted of that my container only takes one little percentage of the sreen and the rest is taken by (section fp-section fp-is-overflow active fp-completely) and I cannot change it, please help.

[This is how I have it, That's the only space available for my div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEgF7.jpg)
[This is the space i want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVqLY.png)
[Here you can see I have my div with height 100% as I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFUTr.png)
[In the second section the div is perfect as well, just as i want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXQVb.jpg)

```
 .container-general {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container-general-2 {
   height: 100%;
   display: grid;
   justify-content: center;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
   overflow: hidden;
   gap: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.container-3{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    overflow: hidden;
    gap: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

first two containers working fine, Third one is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your `height: 100%;` for `height: 100vh`.

That, or use the option `scrollOverflow: false` if you do not plan on having scrollable sections.

```css
.container {
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    vertical-align: middle;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[Online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x7evfLq3/)